# How to enlist all invalid signatures?

Tags: boot, 18.10, secure-boot, signature

My machine keeps prompting of "Invalid Signatures Found" at every single boot. I knew of two kernel modules that had invalid signatures, the NVIDIA display driver module and the vboxdrv module, and I signed them as well. And I am pretty sure they are appropriately signed (as, after appropriate signing, I don't see the symptoms in these two modules), yet I keep getting the "Invalid Signature Found" prompt at every boot. Which, most probably, means that there are some other modules that need appropriate signing.

Is there any method to enlist all such modules that need signing, which may be causing the "Invalid Signature Found" prompts at every boot?